# In TestFlight app build not showing?

Tags: ios, testflight, beta-testing

I released app, now i'm releasing new version of that app. I uploaded successfully, it's build showing in activity.

[image]

But it's build not showing in test flight.

[image]

[image]

My app updated yesterday.

Comment: You must have recieved the mail from iTunes to your registered email id. If its a iOS 11 app (Which I think is the case) then its necessary to pass CFBundleIconName in info.plist. Else you would receive a email which looks like "Missing Info.plist value - A value for the Info.plist key 'CFBundleIconName' is missing in the bundle 'com.***.****'. Apps built with iOS 11 or later SDK must supply app icons in an asset catalog and must also provide a value for this Info.plist key"

Comment: Dear developer,
We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "App Name“. Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery: Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal,

Comment: and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement.  Xcode 8 does not automatically copy the aps-environment entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications in the project editor's Capabilities pane, or manually add the entitlement to your entitlements file. For more information, see

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1.
After you've corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.

Regards,

The App Store team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create .ipa file i'm using Ad Hoc option. But for testing apple send an email like this ....

```
Missing beta entitlement - Your app does not include the beta-reports-active entitlement. If you intend to distribute this build via TestFlight for beta testing, please re-build this app with an App Store Distribution provisioning profile. Do not use ad-hoc profiles.

After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.

Regards,
The App Store team
```

Now i selected App Store option to create .ipa file. Now i uploaded the .ipa through application builder. Then only i'm getting my build in TestFlight.

[image]